# OS X 10.9.2 sending attachments

Tags: macos, mail.app, attachments

I am on a MacBook Pro using OS X 10.9.2, using Mail 7.2
If I try to send an attachment in mail, my finder does not allow me to access files.  I thought maybe it was just taking longer after the update to "adjust" however I left the finder open for 10 minutes and it still nothing.  I can see the folders, but not the contents of the folders.  I can access my files when I go directly through the finder, but not when accessing the finder through the mail.app

HELP!

Comment: workaround: try dragging the file into the email directly from finder (doesn't answer the question but will let you send an important email for now)

Comment: Yes, tried that.  The now the people I'm sending to say they're not getting any attachments.  ARRG!

Answer (score 1):

You can start Disk Utility `Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility` and click **Verify Disk** and **Repair Disk Permissions**.

> However, it seems like a small bug. Just shut down your Mac and
>   restart it, the problem should be gone.

Comment: Ha ha.....of course that was the first thing I tried.